# softbodies collision problem

Tags: collision, soft-body

I have 2 balls (softbody) falling one after the other. The Softbody1 goes first. When the second Softbody2 reaches the initial position of Softbody1 it collides with it, but Softbody1 is already gone, there is no visible geometry there!

Basically the second softbody interact with the orginal position of the first softbody?

Any idea?

Comment: I found a trick by removing the collider modifiers and both balls and adding new ones. Not very handy thous, i'd love to understand what is happening.

Comment: I can’t replicate this. Can you provide a sample .blend file or the steps require to get the described behaviour?